# How could I return a complex calculated array to my arrow-function in Svelte3 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions, svelte

Since the new release of Svelte v3 i am trying to translate my v2 code to the new version. I have translated the computed part into a Javascript arrow-function. I want to set the returned value from the function into the same var in which the arrow function exists. I also tried to do:

`calendar = () => {...}`

but in this case the browser interprets the arrow 
function as a default method.

```js
$: calendar => {
  // Function to calculate the calendar which updates every change
  let calendarArr = [];
  const offset = new Date(
    selectedDate.getFullYear(),
    selectedDate.getMonth(),
    1
  ).getDay();
  //number of days in selected month
  const days =
    32 -
    new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
  //for each potential cell(empty cells + day cells)
  for (let d = 0; d < days + offset; d++) {
    //start new row if 0th, 7th, 14th etc day
    if (d % 7 == 0) calendarArr.push([]);
    //push cell into the row
    calendarArr[Math.trunc(d / 7)].push(
      d - offset < 0
        ? null
        : new Date(
            selectedDate.getFullYear(),
            selectedDate.getMonth(),
            d - offset + 1
          )
    );
  }
  console.log(calendarArr);
  return calendarArr; // -> I want to set this as the calendar value
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reactive statement (`$:`) doesn't have to be an expression that evaluates to a single value. You could do your calculation of `calendarArr` in the reactive statement and then assign that value to another variable in your component.

**Example**

```
let calendar;

$: {
  // Function to calculate the calendar which updates every change
  let calendarArr = [];
  const offset = new Date(
    selectedDate.getFullYear(),
    selectedDate.getMonth(),
    1
  ).getDay();
  //number of days in selected month
  const days =
    32 -
    new Date(selectedDate.getFullYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
  //for each potential cell(empty cells + day cells)
  for (let d = 0; d < days + offset; d++) {
    //start new row if 0th, 7th, 14th etc day
    if (d % 7 == 0) calendarArr.push([]);
    //push cell into the row
    calendarArr[Math.trunc(d / 7)].push(
      d - offset < 0
        ? null
        : new Date(
            selectedDate.getFullYear(),
            selectedDate.getMonth(),
            d - offset + 1
          )
    );
  }
  console.log(calendarArr);
  calendar = calendarArr;
}
```

Comment: This is spot on. To go one step further, we don't even need the temporary variable — you could just do `calendar = []` at the top instead of `let calendarArr = []`, then replace subsequent references to `calendarArr` with `calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just invoke it immediatly like so:

```
calendar = (() => { ... })()
```

But even better would be to give this function a name and then call it:

```
function createCalendar() { ... }

calendar = createCalendar()
```